# How can I structure my program to return successful output of a recursive function?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, sudoku

I'm in the process of making a Sudoku solver (sans walkthrough/cheating with the algorithm). Essentially, my hypothetical function works as follows:

1. Taking a grid as an argument, use basic logic (relying on their being only 1 possible location for a value) to solve it as far as possible without guessing/doing more complicated logic.
2. Once a point is reached where there are no obvious values, find a cell with the minimum possibilities of `n`(usually 2), clone the grid `n` times and substitute the possibilities into the cell, then call the function again for each new grid.
3. If a grid ever has a contradiction, terminate that function call.
4. If the grid is solved, set the class variable `solvedGrid[][]` equal to the solved grid.

In this setup, I would make the class, call the function, and then retrieve the answer from the `solvedGrid[][]` field. My recursive function itself has a `void` return, or perhaps I can make it `boolean` in order to establish that the solution is found. Either way, I can't think of a way to return the `byte[][]` since I will be calling the function multiple times from 1 function instance. Thank you in advance.

(Also, to anybody who's created such a program - would my proposed algorithm actually work?)

Answer (score 1):

Return the solvedGrid, or null if a contradiction was found. No need for making the return value a class member, I would even say bad design. 
And yes, your algorithm sounds good. A depth-first search in the sudoku grid space.